# How to analyze memory usage of an app

Tags: android, memory

I try to debug an Android application which has an out of memory error. The
app cannot allocate 3Mbytes in some condition. I analyze the adb log,
there are some debug output of dalvikvm as below:

```
dalvikvm: GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 47% free 4781K/8967K, external 55469K/57517K, paused 64ms
dalvikvm: GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 47% free 4781K/8967K, external 55469K/57517K, paused 80ms
dalvikvm: GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 47% free 4781K/8967K, external 55469K/57517K, paused 39ms
```

I compare the number in above output with the number in "Heap" window
of DDMS. "free 4781K/8967K" seems corresponding to "Allocated" and
"Heap size" in "Heap" of DDMS. However, I'm not sure what is "external
55469K/57517K". I suspect that it is memory allocated by native code.
Does anybody know this?

Answer (score 1):

It's complicated, so says this Android platform engineer:

[How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813)

3mb is a lot for an Android app, the starting heaps are pretty small, ~16-32mb.